Formula for Probability of rolling higher
Im making a game where players roll virtual dice and add a bonus to it. One such case is when a player wants to make an attack. Let's say Player 1 wants to attack Player 2. Player 1 rolls for Accuracy and adds their bonus to it. Player 2 rolls for Dodge and adds their bonus to it. If Player 1's Accuracy total is higher than Player 2's Dodge total, then Player 1 successfully hits. Player 1 does not hit on ties. What are the chances that Player 1 hits Player 2?
The game is asymmetrical. Players roll different dice and have different bonuses. The die is represented by d[number], where its value can be anywhere from 0 to that number, inclusive. Ex: d15 can roll between 0 and 15, inclusive. Here's some example scenarios:

Example 1: Player 1 rolls d20 + 12, Player 2 rolls d33 + 1
Example 2: Player 1 rolls d8 + 3, Player 2 rolls d36 + 1
Example 3: Player 1 rolls d21 + 5, Player 2 rolls d10 + 7
Example 4: Player 1 rolls d11 + 3, Player 2 rolls d3 + 18

As you can see, there's lots of scenarios where Player 1 can possibly either hit or miss (Ex.1, Ex.2), and there's some scenarios where its either impossible to miss (Ex.3), or impossible to hit (Ex.4).
It might be helpful to think of these examples in terms of ranges instead, where the min value is the bonus, and the max value is the bonus plus the max die roll. Ex: d8 + 3 is functionally the same as 3 to 11, or [3, 11]
Is there a formula that can be used to determine the chance that Player 1 hits, based on their die and bonus and the opponent's die and bonus?

"Ex: d15 can roll between 0 and 15, inclusive" suggests d15 has $16$ possible outcomes.

@Henry yes, that is correct

Let's define $d_1$ and $d_2$ as the labelled die numbers of players 1 and 2 respectively, $b_1$ and $b_2$ as each player's minimum rolled number (aka their bonus), and $D_1$ and $D_2$ as each player's actual result.
Also, because both of our dice are Uniform distributions, and when we are comparing two Uniform distributions, we inevitably get into Triangular Numbers, which are defined as:
$$T(n)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$$
It's going to be useful for us to have a more generalised function, where we can choose our starting number, so we'll define:
$$T(m,n)= \sum_{i=m}^{n}i= \begin{cases}
\dfrac{(n-m+1)(n+m)}{2} & \text{ if } m \leq n \\ 
0 & \text{ if } m > n 
\end{cases}$$
Finally, we're going to define a couple of shorthands:
$$\Delta_d=d_1-d_2$$
$$\Delta_b=b_1-b_2$$
These should let us build our functions a bit more compactly.
Let's first look at the simplest case - where both dice have the same distribution. This is a pretty well-solved problem - we know that the solution is:
$$P(D_1>D_2)=\frac{T(d_1)}{(d_1+1)^2}= \frac{d_1(d_1+1)}{2(d_1+1)^2}$$
It's also relatively simple to generalise this for $d_1\neq d_2$ - using our more generalised triangle number sum, we can write such a function as:
$$P(D_1>D_2)=\frac{T(\max[1,\Delta_d],d_1)}{(d_1+1)(d_2+1)}= \frac{(d_1-\max[1,\Delta_d]+1)(d_1+\max[1,\Delta_d])}{2(d_1+1)(d_2+1)}$$
In effect, if $d_2$ is bigger, it won't affect the numerator (because then $\Delta_d < 1$) but if it's smaller, it will increase the starting point of our triangle sum.
Dealing with $b_1 \neq b_2$ is a more difficult question - $\Delta_b$ always changes the start of our triangle sum, but if $\Delta_b$ is positive, it also results in $D_1$ outcomes that are automatic wins, and if $\Delta_b$ is negative, it also reduces the terminus of our triangle sum. Fortunately, with the right $\max$ and $\min$ functions we can construct a single function that takes all of that into account:
$$
\begin{align*}P(D_1>D_2)&=\frac{\min[\max[0,\Delta_b],d_2+1](d_1+1)+T(\max[1,\Delta_d+\Delta_b],d_1+\min[0,\Delta_b])}{(d_1+1)(d_2+1)}\\
&=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } d_2 < \Delta_b\\
0 & \text{ if } d_1 + \Delta_b \leq 0\\
\frac{\max[0,\Delta_b](d_1+1)+\frac{1}{2}(d_1+\min[0,\Delta_b]-\max[1,\Delta_d+\Delta_b]+1)(d_1+\min[0,\Delta_b]+\max[1,\Delta_d+\Delta_b])}{(d_1+1)(d_2+1)} & \text{ otherwise }  \\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
Alternatively, for calculation purposes, it's probably a lot easier to just compare $D_1>D_2$ across every possible outcome and count up the results, in effect reducing the formula to:
$$P(D_1>D_2)=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{d_1}\sum_{k=0}^{d_2}[j+b_1>k+b_2]}{(d_1+1)(d_2+1)}$$
Where our square brackets denote Iverson brackets. A simple Excel LAMBDA function that follows this approach and will give you the probability for any $d_1$,$d_2$,$b_1$ and $b_2$ is:
=LAMBDA(
    d_1,b_1,d_2,b_2,
    LET(
        matrix, --(SEQUENCE(d_1+1,1,b_1,1)>SEQUENCE(1,d_2+1,b_2,1)),
        SUM(matrix)/COUNT(matrix)
    )
)

Or, without the whitespace:
=LAMBDA(d_1,b_1,d_2,b_2,LET(matrix,--(SEQUENCE(d_1+1,1,b_1,1)>SEQUENCE(1,d_2+1,b_2,1)), 
SUM(matrix)/COUNT(matrix)))

This function builds arrays of each die's probability space, makes each comparison, converts the boolean results from TRUE/FALSE to 1/0, then sums up the total array, divided by the number of outcomes in the array, which gives an equivalent result to the final equation.

here's an example of my excel formula, for easy copy+paste:

=LAMBDA(d_1,b_1,d_2,b_2, LET( matrix, --(SEQUENCE(d_1+1,1,b_1,1)>SEQUENCE(1,d_2+1,b_2,1)), SUM(matrix)/COUNT(matrix) ))(50,100,50,100)

@shieldgenerator7 good idea, I've added that to the answer.

We can solve this with brute force. Suppose player $1$ rolls $\mathrm dn_1+k_1$ and player 2 rolls $\mathrm dn_2+k_2$. Observe that player 1 needs to roll a $(k_2-k_1+1)$ to have a chance of winning. Also if player 1 rolls $(n_2+k_2-k_1+1)$, they automatically win. Suppose player 1 rolls $k_2-k_1+i$, where $i\in \{\max(k_1-k_2,1),\ldots, \min(n_2,n_1-k_2+k_1)\}$. In this case player 2 must roll at most $i-1$ with probability $\frac{i}{n_2+1}$. Putting this together:
$$
\mathbb P[\text{p1}>\text{p2}]=\frac 1{n_1+1}\Bigg(\min\Big(0,n_1+k_1-n_2-k_2\Big)+\sum_{i=\max(k_1-k_2,1)}^{\min(n_2,n_1-k_2+k_1)}\frac{i}{n_2+1}\Bigg).
$$
There are lots of cases. This can be simplified more in the case where $n_1+k_1\geq n_2+k_2$, but $k_1\leq k_2+1$. Note that $\sum_{i=1}^{n_2}i=n_2(n_2+1)/2$.
$$
\mathbb P[\text{p1}>\text{p2}]=\frac 1{n_1+1}\Bigg(n_1+k_1-n_2-k_2+\frac{n_2}{2}\Bigg)=\frac 1{n_1+1}\Bigg(n_1-\frac{n_2}{2}+k_1-k_2\Bigg).
$$
Note that if $n_1=n_2$ and $k_1=k_2$ then this gives ${n_1\choose 2}/(n_1)^2$, which makes sense. Now consider the case where $n_1+k_1<n_2+k_2$, but $n_1+k_1>k_2$ (so there is a chance of winning). Let's still assume $k_1\leq k_2+1$.
$$
\mathbb P[\text{p1}>\text{p2}]=\frac{(n_1+k_1-k_2)(n_1+k_1-k_2+1)}{2(n_1+1)(n_2+1)}
$$
Closing Remark Note that $k_1-k_2$ always appears together, since the relative difference in bonus is all that matters. Because of this, we may generally assume that $k_2=0$.
Extra For the case where $k_1>k_2+1$, you can modify the formulae above to switch players 1 and 2.

thanks so much! so the first formula is the general case, and the second formula is the lead up to the third formula, which is the formula for one specific case? did i get that right? do i need all 3 or just the first one?

I made a visualiazation for this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xkjplsy1zp

The first formula is general, the second and third are each about two specific cases

@ploosu2 Your visualization is practically an answer to the question. At the very least it gives a highly intuitive way to solve any problem of this kind. Do you think you can build it into an answer you can post?
